# Prevent GitHub pull request merging before AppVeyor check is finished

Tags: github, continuous-integration, appveyor

There is a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=) with AppVeyor check enabled for pull requests. When I create a pull request and wait for the check to complete, the PR is [marked as green](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/pull/156):

[image]

In the same time there is a possibility to merge a PR when the check is *in progress*. In this case the PR is displayed as [failed](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/pull/159), but the changes (potentially undesirable) are merged:

[image]

Is it possible to make the check required and prevent unvalidated pull requests from being completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [protected branches](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/) is what you need, if I understood you correctly.